# Splitting a report into new workbooks

Tags: excel, vba, report

I have a report that lists financial data by employee.  I want to use a macro so I can split the report up by name, and then that creates a separate workbook for each individual employee.

I have the below VBA codes, which work fine, but it only splits in by employee on the same report, by creating a new tab for each person in the existing report. I would like this to action the same, but for it to create a new workbook for each employee, instead of creating a new tab for each employee on the existing report.

What do I need to amend in order to achieve this?

```
Sub parse_data()
Dim lr As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim vcol, i As Integer
Dim iCol As Long
Dim myarr As Variant
Dim title As String
Dim titlerow As Integer

'This macro splits data into multiple worksheets based on the variables on a column found in Excel.
'An InputBox asks you which columns you'd like to filter by, and it just creates these worksheets.

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
vcol = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Which column would you like to filter by?", title:="Filter column", Default:="3", Type:=1)
Set ws = ActiveSheet
lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, vcol).End(xlUp).Row
title = "A1"
titlerow = ws.Range(title).Cells(1).Row
iCol = ws.Columns.Count
ws.Cells(1, iCol) = "Unique"
For i = 2 To lr
    On Error Resume Next
    If ws.Cells(i, vcol) <> "" And Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ws.Cells(i, vcol), ws.Columns(iCol), 0) = 0 Then
        ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, iCol).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = ws.Cells(i, vcol)
    End If
Next

myarr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ws.Columns(iCol).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants))
ws.Columns(iCol).Clear

For i = 2 To UBound(myarr)
    ws.Range(title).AutoFilter Field:=vcol, Criteria1:=myarr(i) & ""
    If Not Evaluate("=ISREF('" & myarr(i) & "'!A1)") Then
        Sheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = myarr(i) & ""
    Else
        Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Move after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
    End If
    ws.Range("A" & titlerow & ":A" & lr).EntireRow.Copy Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Range("A1")
    'Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Columns.AutoFit
Next

ws.AutoFilterMode = False
ws.Activate
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Workbooks.Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbooks.add)

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub parse_data()

    'This macro splits data into multiple worksheets
    'based on the variables on a column found in Excel.
    'An InputBox asks you which columns you'd like
    'to filter by, and it just creates these worksheets.
    
    Const TITLE_ROW = 1

    Dim wbOut As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet, wsOut As Worksheet
    Dim iLastRow As Long, iRow As Long
    Dim iFilterCol As Integer
    Dim sPath As String
    
    ' get filter column nu,ber
    iFilterCol = Application.InputBox( _
            prompt:="Which column would you like to filter by?", _
            title:="Filter column", Default:="3", Type:=1)

    If iFilterCol < 1 Then
        MsgBox iFilterCol & " not valid", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    sPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
    iLastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, iFilterCol).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim dict As Object, key
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    ' get unique values using dictionary
    For iRow = TITLE_ROW + 1 To iLastRow
        key = Trim(ws.Cells(iRow, iFilterCol))
        If Not dict.exists(key) Then
            dict.Add key, iRow
        End If
    Next
     
    ' create separate workbooks
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each key In dict
    
        ' apply filter
        ws.Rows(TITLE_ROW).AutoFilter Field:=iFilterCol, Criteria1:=key
        
        ' create new workbook
        Set wbOut = Workbooks.Add
        Set wsOut = wbOut.Sheets(1)
        wsOut.Name = key
        ws.Range("A" & TITLE_ROW & ":A" & iLastRow).EntireRow.Copy wsOut.Range("A1")
        wsOut.Columns.AutoFit
        ' save and close
        wbOut.SaveAs (sPath & key & ".xlsx")
        wbOut.Close False
    
    Next
   
    ws.Activate
    ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox dict.Count & " workbooks created", vbInformation
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi there - thank you very much for your reply. I have just tried to run the above, but unfortunately it has an error message.

 'Compile Error:  Invalid outside procedure' - and it has highlighted the 'Set wb = ActiveWorkbook line.  

Would you know how I could rectify this, please?

Comment: @Khyber That code is to replace  your `For i = 2 To UBound(myarr)..Next` loop.

Comment: Thanks for the update!  So I would need to delete the below, and add your above part in?


For i = 2 To UBound(myarr)
    ws.Range(title).AutoFilter Field:=vcol, Criteria1:=myarr(i) & ""
    If Not Evaluate("=ISREF('" & myarr(i) & "'!A1)") Then
        Sheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = myarr(i) & ""
    Else
        Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Move after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
    End If
    ws.Range("A" & titlerow & ":A" & lr).EntireRow.Copy Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Range("A1")
    'Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Columns.AutoFit

Comment: Wow! That is amazing - thank you so much!! That is brilliant, cant thank you enough!!

Comment: Apologies for the further question!  I have realised that I will need to do this for mutliple worksheets. Ie: the one main report has around 20 tabs in, and I need to pick up the data in each tab depending on the persons name (the persons name in the main summary sheet is in Column B, and first name is in B2).

So the above macro is perfect, but I need it to also pick up the data in the other tabs before it saves down the newly created reports.  

Is this difficult to do?  Apologies, I should have realised this at the start!

Comment: @Khyber Simplest way would be to aggregate the 20 sheets into a temporary sheet first. How many rows in total on all sheets approximately are there? How many new workbooks to create?

Comment: Hi there - unfortunately it is quite hard to do that as none of it is in the same format. As in, the columns are not in the same place in each tab, and each report relates to a different element, so its hard to have a summary sheet without breaking the data down into separate tabs. 

I would say there are around 20 tabs with varying data on.   Sounds like it is quite hard to achieve then?

Comment: That does make it a bit more difficult ! The key is the column with person-name. It does not matter if in a different position on each sheet **providing** there is a way the macro can determine it, for example, by searching the header rows for an identifying word or pattern. However person name is not usually a good key because 2 people sometimes have the same name, or use different spellings, or change name when they marry. Some sort of ID number is much better.